# Gensim - index_to_key gives numbers instead of words as output

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to get 5 most frequent words from word2vec model created from wikipedia dump. I turned this model into KeyedVectors and the code looks like that:

```
 from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
        
   def vocabulary():
        model = KeyedVectors.load("vectors.kv")
        result = model.index_to_key[:5]
        print(result)
```

The result is:
[(507, 1), (858, 1), (785, 1), (251, 1), (9807, 1)]

On the other hand, when i'm trying the same with model made of tokenized text the result is:
['pdop', 'podany', 'wału', 'wytrzymałości', 'skręcanie']

Why am I getting numbers instead of words from the first model?

I used .get_texts() function, but I can't split the result of this function and pass it as sentences value to initiate the model, so I tried creating model with one short article, and then train it with data from .get_texts() article by article like this:

```
    wiki_txt = wiki.get_texts()
    model = Word2Vec.load('wiki_w2v.model')
    for i in wiki_txt:
       article = list(i)
       model.train(article,total_examples = 1, epochs = 1)
```

Even if at this point article is a list[str], model still can't learn the data.

Answer (score 0):

In a `KeyedVectors` from a Gensim `Word2Vec` model, the `index_to_key` property is usually a plain Python list, where each entry is a string word.

That yours are not this suggests something atypical happened during training. Perhaps the corpus that was fed to the `Word2Vec` model was made up of lists-of-tuples, rather than lists-of-string-tokens?

You should go back to the code which initially created & saved that `vectors.kv` file, with special attention to the corpus that was used for training. (What was its first element? Didi it look like a usual text-of-words – a list of strings – or something else?)

**Updates based on comments below:**

It looks like you are providing an literal instance of `WikiCorpus` to `Word2Vec` as the `sentences` argument. That's not the sort of corpus – a sequence where each item is a list-of-words – that `Word2Vec` expects.

The iterator returned by `wiki.get_texts()` is closer – it's the right format, a sequence-of-lists-of-words –but it only passes over the dump once, wherease `Word2Vec` needs something it can re-iterate over for multiple passes.

I recommend one of these three options:

1. Writing your own wrapper iterable class, which will call `wiki.get_texts()` again each time a new iteration is requested; or...
2. Writing some code to iterate through `wiki.get_texts()` once, writing each text into a giant plain-text file, with one article per line. Then, run `Word2Vec` using that file as input; or...
3. If you're one a giant-memory machine that can load the whole corpus as a list, you could do `corpus_list = list(wiki.get_texts()`, then pass that `corpus_list` as the training data to `Word2Vec`.

Separately:

If your only goal is doing a `Word2Vec` training, you don't really need to do the long-running expensive initial load of the WikiCorpus (`wiki = WikiCorpus('plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2') then re-save. That does a time-consuming vocabulary survey of the dump that isn't even consulted by later word2vec training, which does its own survey.

Instead, when you need to use the dump, you can just do:

```py
wiki = WikiCorpus('plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2', dictionary=dict())
```

That leaves the `wiki` object ready for operations like `.get_texts()`, without wastefully creating a redundant dictionary.

Comment: I've made my model firstly using wikipedia dump file **plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2** this way:  `wiki = WikiCorpus('plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2')
    tfidf = TfidfModel(wiki)
    wiki.save('wiki.corpus')
    tfidf.save('wiki.tfidf.model')` This way, I've got 2 files: wiki.corpus and wiki.tfidf model.

Comment: Later i used this code to turn wiki.corpus file into word2vec model: `wiki = WikiCorpus.load('wiki.corpus')
    model = Word2Vec(sentences = wiki, vector_size = 300, window = 10, min_count = 20, workers = max(1, multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1), sample = 1e-3)
    word_vectors = model.wv
    word_vectors.save('vectors.kv')` and as result i've got another 2 files: vectors.kv and vectors.kv.vectors.npy. I'm not sure what's exacly in wiki.corpus file.

Comment: Note you can edit your question to include source code, with formattting, that's easier to read. I've expanded the answer to highlight the problems in the code you've shared.

Comment: Sorry for making such a mess in comments.
I've managed to create a model with the source code I tried to use before for this site: [link](https://gist.github.com/maxbellec/85d90d3d7f2f96589f1517e5c4567dc3)
Thanks to your advices I understood what I've been doing wrong and I replaced the WikiCorpus part with `wiki = WikiCorpus('plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2', dictionary=dict())'` as you recommended, worked perfectly!